# Oracle Linux, prevent Network Adapter from sleep when running in VirtualBox on macOS

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

I have installed Oracle Linux 7 with the current version of VirtualBox, running on mac OS Sierra with a macbook. It therefore has a battery but is plugged in at all times.

For networking I use 2 adapters, one NAT for internet and one Host-Guest for ssh etc.

For some time now I was always wondering why I would get a broken ssh pipe, trial and error showed me that the VM will go to sleep (black screen), which causes the network adapter to break, telling me the name of the adapter and simply *Reset adapter* as soon as I wake it up again by typing into the vm itself.

I can then restart the network adapter via /etc/init.d/network restart and it will work again

Any ideas how I can change that? My Linux skills are very limited and I am not even sure what Oracle Linux is based on, most tips I find online do not work, no GUI also makes it difficult to just hop into power settings or something similar

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on Windows host machine.

Configure your network adapter to

1) Allow the network adapter to wake the computer,

2) Allow a magic packet to wake the computer,

3) Allow IPV6

http://www.worldstart.com/dropped-internet-connection-in-sleep-mode/

Now, when I sleep my computer, and then wake it up, I get networking on both the host and guest, not just host.